# Objects move when initial pearenting is done

Tags: bones, constraints, parent

So in the bone constraints tab I want to make a bone_a a child of bone_root and I have to use the Make Child Of constraint in the bone constraints tab because of how my rig is, but I do not want any bones to move when I parent them initially, I want them to move when I move the bone, not when I initially parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After add *Child Of* constrain to your bone, Make sure you press *Clear Inverse* then press *Set Inverse* button.
[image]